# What happened to esp smartconfig, it's a broken mess in v4.1?

Tags: esp32

For one thing, esp_smartconfig_start no longer accepts a callback.  They did away with the smartconfig_status_t enum, apparently/approximately replacing it with smartconfig_event_t, but nothing references that type, I searched the sources.

Really strange, the docs say (and headers concur) to use esp_esptouch_set_timeout to set a timeout -- esptouch, really?  And the docs mention SC_STATUS_FIND_CHANNEL (as when the timeout starts counting) that doesn't even exist anymore (it was part of smartconfig_status_t.)

Is smartconfig even nominally workable in 4.1, or am I missing something?  (I was using the status callbacks, not sure if I can work around losing them -- this is a pretty big set back.)

Comment: Have a look at the example [smartconfig_main.c](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/wifi/smart_config/main/smartconfig_main.c). `esp_event_handler_register` is used to register callbacks and the `event_id` is compared with the `smartconfig_event_t` members.

Comment: Thanks, should've looked at the example.  I'm going to stick with 3.3.3 for now -- I hate breaking changes.  I take it they are moving toward a consistent registration handler?  But what could be more intuitive than passing the callback function to the function that invokes?